# How do I know a div height before making it visible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, jquery-animate

I have a slide-open visible / slide-close hidden div.

That effect is achieved by animate()ing div's height.

The problem is that div is shared by multiple content (different text paragraphs) which their height's are not known ahead.

So how do I know how the height of the div will be when I put in such content so that I can animate('height':'-px') to slide-open the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `slideDown()` and you won't need to calculate the height.

The only other way you could do (but I don't know your exact circumstances) is to `clone()` the element and append it to the document, set its `height` to `auto`, and then get the `height()` of that.

```
var cloned = $('#some-element').clone();

cloned.css({ position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px', height: 'auto' });

var height = cloned.height();

cloned.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick that worked for me before is to set the element's opacity to something really low, like `0.01`. This performs a `show` on the element, but if your opacity is sufficiently low, it will barely be noticeable on the page.

Comment: This has problems, for example, it will fill the space required to render the element. You may as well use `visibility: hidden`.